# Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in PHP prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

so I'm trying my hand at PDO for a project after referring to w3schools but I keep getting this error

> Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean

here's my code. I cannot figure out whats causing it

```
if (isset($data->title) && isset($data->content) && isset($data->lang) && isset($data->show_on_site)) {
    $response = array();
    try {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO newsposts
            (heading, content, author, language,show_on_page)
             VALUES (:title, :content,:author,:lang,:show_on_site)';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $db->real_escape_string($data->title), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':content', $db->real_escape_string($data->content), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':author', $_SESSION['user_session'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lang', $db->real_escape_string($data->lang), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':show_on_site', $db->real_escape_string($data->show_on_site), PDO::PARAM_BOOL);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            header_status(200);
            $response['status'] = 'Success';
            $response['message'] = 'Post Inserted';
        } else {
            header_status(400);
            $response['status'] = 'Error';
            $response['message'] = 'Something went wrong';
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    } catch (exception $e) {
        header_status(503);
        $response['status'] = 'Error';
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Comment: If `prepare()` fails it might return `FALSE`. I think it would be the cause, but do not see why would it fail...

Comment: Try changing `$stmt->bindParam(':show_on_site', $db->real_escape_string($data->show_on_site), PDO::PARAM_BOOL);` to `$stmt->bindParam(':show_on_site', $db->real_escape_string($data->show_on_site), PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: Where did you define `$db` and Do you have a check like `if($db instanceof PDO)` before prepare ?

Comment: Error is related with `$db`. Connection is not made with database, so connection function returned `false`. That is what causing error.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto yes you're right, the `$db->prepare($sql)` part returns false. But why is it happening?

Comment: @mim. the $db instance is prepared in a config file which I have required at the top on my page before starting the SQL

Comment: @CDsouza check `table name, column name` with database `table names & column names`. `Can not find column name` might be error. use `try catch`.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation states](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-returnvalues):

> If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement,
>   PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) (depending on [error
>   handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)).

so try to set "error mode" in your `$db` object to "exception" with

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and wrap `prepare()` call in "try-catch" block to figure out what's going wrong, like this

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```